# How to get the first and the last record per group in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can a `select` be crafted to where the first and last row of each set of the rows are grouped with a `GROUP BY`.

I've this table with the following data:

```
id  group   val   start   end
1   10      36    465     89        
2   10      35    55      11        
3   10      34    20      456       
4   20      38   1140     1177      
5   20      22    566     788       
6   20      1235  789     4796      
7   20      7894  741     1067
```

What I need to get is the first value of the column start and last value of the column end with group by the group column.

The resultant table should be as below:

```
   id  group   val   start   end
    1   10      36    465     89
    3   10      34    20      456       
    4   20      38   1140     1177
    7   20      7894  741     1067
```

I did a query but with `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` and `over (partition by)`. It works in SQL Server 2012 but didn't work in SQL Server 2008. I need a query that can be executed in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: The `MIN` val for `group = 20` should be `22`, `id = 5`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about using `ROW_NUMBER`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/1253/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RnAsc = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [group] ORDER BY val),
        RnDesc = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [group] ORDER BY val DESC)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    id, [group], val, start, [end]
FROM Cte
WHERE
    RnAsc = 1 OR RnDesc = 1
ORDER BY [group], val
```

Comment: Solution with `ROW_NUMBER` works efficiently if your table is small or number of elements per group is small. If your table is big and number of elements per group is large and you have a separate table with the list of all group `IDs`, then `CROSS APPLY` with appropriate index would be more efficient. For example, your table has 100M rows and there are only 10K groups. `ROW_NUMBER` would have to read all 100M rows, calculate row number for all of them (in the suggested solution most likely twice), then discard most of the work, while you really need to read only 20K rows.

Answer (score 6):

This is one way -

```
select  t.*
from    tbl t
join    (
        select [group],
               min(val) as val_1,
               max(val) as val_2
        from   tbl
        group by [group]
        ) v
     on t.[group] = v.[group]
    and (t.val = v.val_1
     or t.val = v.val_2);
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c682f/1/0

Another approach:

```
select id, [group], val, [start], [end]
from(
select t.*,
       max(val) over(partition by [group]) as max_grp,
       min(val) over(partition by [group]) as min_grp
from tbl t
) x
where val in (max_grp,min_grp)
```

Answer (score 0):

How to two query 'UNION'

```
SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeId, AttendenceId, Intime
FROM EmployeeAttendence
WHERE AttendenceDate >='1/18/2020 00:00:00' 
  AND AttendenceDate <='1/18/2020 23:59:59'
GROUP BY EmployeeId,AttendenceId,Intime
ORDER BY AttendenceId  

SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeId, AttendenceId, OutTime
FROM EmployeeAttendence
WHERE AttendenceDate >='1/18/2020 00:00:00' 
  AND AttendenceDate <='1/18/2020 23:59:59'
GROUP BY EmployeeId, AttendenceId, OutTime
ORDER BY AttendenceId desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bankaccount example:

```
create table transactions (
id integer identity(1,1),
aDateTime datetime not null default getdate(),
OnHand float,
AmountWithDrawn float,
AmountDeposited float,
NewOnhand float
)

insert into transactions (aDateTime, OnHand, AmountWithDrawn, AmountDeposited, NewOnhand) values ('01-jan-2021 08:15', 0, 0, 1000, 1000);

insert into transactions (aDateTime, OnHand, AmountWithDrawn, AmountDeposited, NewOnhand) values ('05-jan-2021 08:15', 1000, 100, 0, 900);

insert into transactions (aDateTime, OnHand, AmountWithDrawn, AmountDeposited, NewOnhand) values ('06-jan-2021 08:15', 900, 200, 0, 700);

insert into transactions (aDateTime, OnHand, AmountWithDrawn, AmountDeposited, NewOnhand) values ('01-feb-2021 08:15', 700, 0, 1000, 1700);

insert into transactions (aDateTime, OnHand, AmountWithDrawn, AmountDeposited, NewOnhand) values ('09-feb-2021 08:15', 1700, 200, 0, 1500);

insert into transactions (aDateTime, OnHand, AmountWithDrawn, AmountDeposited, NewOnhand) values ('10-feb-2021 08:15', 1500, 300, 0, 1200);

insert into transactions (aDateTime, OnHand, AmountWithDrawn, AmountDeposited, NewOnhand) values ('01-mar-2021 08:15', 1200, 0, 1000, 2200);

insert into transactions (aDateTime, OnHand, AmountWithDrawn, AmountDeposited, NewOnhand) values ('07-mar-2021 08:15', 2200, 400, 0, 1800);

insert into transactions (aDateTime, OnHand, AmountWithDrawn, AmountDeposited, NewOnhand) values ('11-mar-2021 08:15', 1800, 500, 0, 1300);
```

List:

```
select * from transactions order by id
```

[image]

Now we want to group per month:

```
select distinct month(adatetime) aMonth, sum(amountWithDrawn) SumWithDrawn, sum(amountDeposited) SumDeposited from transactions group by month(adatetime);
```

[image]

But how can we get Onhand and NewOnhand in the query?

```
with cte as
(select distinct month(adatetime) aMonth, sum(amountWithDrawn) SumWithDrawn, sum(amountDeposited) SumDeposited, min(id) MinId, max(id) MaxId from transactions group by month(adatetime)) 
select aMonth, (select Onhand from transactions where id = minid) FirstOnhand, SumWithDrawn, SumDeposited, (select NewOnhand from transactions where id = maxid) LastNewOnhand from cte
```

[image]

This way would be quite efficient (add index to ID) and the code quite is easy to read and comprehend.

Answer (score -1):

```
select tt.id, tt.groups, tt.val, x.sstart, tt.[end] from test_table tt join
(Select groups,First_value(start) over (partition by groups order by groups) sstart from test_table  
Union
Select groups,Last_Value(start) over (partition by groups order by groups) sstart from test_table) as x
on tt.start=x.sstart
Order by tt.groups, sstart Desc
```

Comment: Can you explain why this should answer OP question ?

Comment: The OP did clearly ask for a solution in SQL Server 2008, without `FIRST_VALUE` or `LAST_VALUE`.