# Duplicate Rows - SQL Server Groupby and Union

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, union

I have some data similar to the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------
Location  Weight  MarkedOldest  plantId  Date
--------------------------------------------------
101010    520     0             2        3/10/2019
105000    500     1             2        3/1/2019
105000    500     0             2        2/20/2019
```

And a requirement to be able to override the oldest row in this table. I introduced the column MarkedOldest here to preserve the actual date the row was created. At first glance, you see that the last row in the table is the oldest, but say the user wants to set the second row as the oldest. No problem.

My problem arises when I'm returning a list of these rows with requirements to present the sum weight at each location, with the oldest location presented first. *Ideal output for a query like this would return this:*

```
105000  1000lbs  (3/1 and 2/20)
101010  520lbs   3/10
```

I have written the following query which has gotten close:

```
select z.Location, Sum(z.Weight), as Weight, z.Date
FROM 
  (select Location, Weight, MarkedOldest
   from dbo.SomeTable WHERE MarkedOldest = 1 PlantId= 2 
   UNION
   select Location, Weight, MarkedOldest
   from dbo.SomeTable WHERE PlantId = 2) as z
Group by z.Location, z.MarkedOldest
Order By z.MarkedOldest desc
```

This query produces the following output:

```
105000  500lbs  3/1/2019
105000  500lbs  2/20/2019
101010  520lbs  3/10/2019
```

The idea here was to select any manually entered oldest rows first and union them with remaining rows in a oldest first order. The above output is almost correct, but I would like to merge/remove duplicate locations over the top two rows. I don't think I can do this however, because I am grouping by columns 'MarkedOldest' and 'Date'

Is there any other way I can solve this query to get the expected output? I've been met with lots of groupBy/aggregate errors when trying things like removing some groupby or orderby columns.

Comment: Instead of constantly updating MarkedOldest, I would just create a `VIEW`. Then, you can use `row_number()` or another window function like `rank()` to get / mark your rows and do your aggregations. There are [lots of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751913/retrieving-last-record-in-each-group-from-database-sql-server-2005-2008) on how to get the ["most current for a group" or "latest record for a group"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128202/how-to-get-the-first-and-the-last-record-per-group-in-sql/31128232) on SO.

Comment: @scsimon FWIW, I wouldn't bother with a view

Comment: Fair point @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by making the top half of your UNION include the row "Marked Oldest" AND all the rows that preceded it in time.

```
WHERE Date<=(SELECT Date FROM MyTable WHERE MarkedOldest=1)
```

You can then GROUP and Aggregate that half of the UNION, and make the bottom half just include the rows that come after the row "Marked Oldest".

```
WHERE Date>(SELECT Date FROM MyTable WHERE MarkedOldest=1)
```

The code snippets above assume that the row "Marked Oldest" cannot have the same exact date as another row that is not "Marked Oldest".   If that IS possible, then you would have to decide what you want to do with the other row and code accordingly.

Comment: This didn't work out for me. I'm probably doing something wrong though. Because I have to select MarkedOldest in the parent query to present the manually oldest row first (by the order desc), it must grouped by it as well which breaks up the two 100500 locations into separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

i focused on you ideal output and if you putt you current output into CTE and make some data conversions you can try this query:

```
WITH data as(
SELECT 105000 id ,CAST(LEFT('500lbs',LEN('500lbs')-3) AS numeric) AS lbs,  '3/1/2019' AS date union all
SELECT 105000 id ,LEFT('500lbs',LEN('500lbs')-3) AS lbs,  '2/20/2019' AS date union all
SELECT 101010 id ,LEFT('520lbs',LEN('520lbs')-3) AS lbs,  '3/1/2019' AS date
)

SELECT 
    ID
    ,CAST(SUM(lbs) as VARCHAR) +'lbs' lbs
    ,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ' and ' + d2.date
                     FROM data d2
                     WHERE d1.ID = d2.ID
                 FOR XML PATH('')) , 1, 5, '') AS  date
FROM data d1
GROUP BY ID
```